# What was the batch size used in the original GoogleNet paper (Inception)?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, computer-vision

It does not seem to be explicitly mentioned in the methods of the paper (available at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.4842.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

As you correctly note the batch-size specification is not available in the original publication. That said, it is probably `128` based on circumstantial evidence.

Circumstantial evidence:
Caffe replicates GoogLeNet [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/master/models/bvlc_googlenet) using a batch-size of 128 where it is explicitly mentioned that: "*This model is a replication of the model described in the GoogleNet publication. We would like to thank Christian Szegedy* (the first author of the GoogLeNet paper) *for all his help in the replication of GoogleNet model.*" In addition a batch-size of 128 is used by NVidia to run standard speed benchmarks [here](https://nvidianews.nvidia.com/news/new-nvidia-pascal-gpus-accelerate-deep-learning-inference) when using GoogLeNet.

(This *not* a definite answer so please feel to post another answer if you have a more authoritative source. Personally, 128 seems somewhat too big... I would suspect 10 would be more appropriate for a competition but there even less evidence for size 10 online...)

Comment: That's very interesting, thanks. When using NVidia's DIGITS for quick prototyping, there's a fill in box where one can change the batch size -- if left blank it will be the network "default". But that default size is nowhere t be found... in my case, due to memory limitations I use 4.